# Fullcalendar custom view based on month view

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to build up a calendar application for students. I use 4 different views: day, week, month and semester. The semester view is a customized one and it would work fine if  it wasn't that by default it has the layout based on the week view and not on the month one that would be much better.

Right now the only thing I do is to specify the extra view in the parameter "view" of the fullcalendar constructor:

```
views: {
        agendaSixMonth: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { months: 6 },
            buttonText: 'Semestre',
            start: $.fullCalendar.moment(startSemester),
            end: $.fullCalendar.moment(endSemester),
            intervalStart: $.fullCalendar.moment(startSemester),
            intervalEnd: $.fullCalendar.moment(endSemester),
        }
    }
```

I can't find in the documentation how to set the layout of custom views and I was wondering if someone knows if it's possible eventually by setting a parameter in "views" or if I have to code everything from scratch. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was as simple as setting type to month :)
Easy peasy!!
Final working solution:

```
views: {
    agendaSixMonth: {
        type: 'month',
        duration: { months: 6 },
        buttonText: 'Semestre',
        start: $.fullCalendar.moment(startSemester),
        end: $.fullCalendar.moment(endSemester),
        intervalStart: $.fullCalendar.moment(startSemester),
        intervalEnd: $.fullCalendar.moment(endSemester),
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't get any answer and I posted the solution I found myself... Should I upvote my own question??

Comment: You should answer it properly, so in future who ever refer this can get help from your answer